# How to use 'Between' operator for DATEs in Teradata?

Tags: teradata

I want to  restrict the rows I retrieve by using 'between' for two dates.

The 'saledate' column I used has the following infomation

```
SALEDATE DATE FORMAT 'YYYY-MM-DD' NOT NULL
```

The code I used:

```
SELECT *
FROM trnsact
WHERE saledate BETWEEN '2005-01-01' AND '2005-06-30';
```

And then I got an error 'Error Code - 3535 
Error Message - [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.09] [Error 3535][SQLState 22003] 
A character string failed conversion to a numeric value.'

I also tried with DATE:

```
SELECT *
FROM trnsact
WHERE saledate BETWEEN DATE '2005-01-01' AND DATE '2005-06-30';
```

But end up with another error
    Error Message - [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.09] [Error 3706] [SQLState 42000] Syntax error: Invalid DATE Literal.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Those *date literals* are fully valid, can you try a simple `SELECT DATE '2005-01-01', DATE '2005-06-30;'?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `DATE` literals:

```
SELECT *
FROM trnsact
WHERE saledate BETWEEN DATE '2005-01-01' AND DATE '2005-06-31';
```

Comment: Hi! thx for your reply. but I received another error after trying with 'DATE' literals...

Answer (score 0):

try below query for teradata. It's too late though.

```
SELECT *
FROM trnsact
WHERE saledate BETWEEN 
    to_date('2005-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD') AND 
    to_date('2005-06-30','YYYY-MM-DD') ;
```

Comment: There's no need to apply TO_DATE, a *date literal* is much easier. Btw, supported by Oracle, too :-)